# No GA trackingId defined, when updating GA to GA4

Tags: reactjs, extjs, google-analytics

Trying to Update GA to GA4 with [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@analytics/google-analytics), but does not work and got the following console errors as we can see from the picture below.

```
import Analytics from 'analytics'
import googleAnalytics from '@analytics/google-analytics'


const analytics = Analytics({
  app: 'hhhhhhh',
  plugins: [
    googleAnalytics({
      measurementIds: ['G-VW5LRJYXME']
    })
  ]
})

export default analytics
```

[image]

The measurementID is correct.